# Android setRequestedOrientation is not working as expected inside onResume

Tags: android

I have an activity that is locked in landscape from manifest. One of my fragments requires Portrait mode. Before I switch to that fragment I call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` on my activity.

This works fine, however if I attempt to `setRequestedOrientation` from onResume (normally if the Portrait fragment was the last one opened by the user and the activity got restarted), I still get my activity drawn in landscape.

Bug or I'm missing some lifecycle trick here?

Comment: Does your onResume know about the switch in displayed fragments?  If you're restarting the activity it will probably be drawn per the manifest.

Comment: It works fine if I set orientation inside my fragment's ```onViewCreated()``` but ideally I'd like to do this before fragment gets initialised..

Comment: @KristyWelsh yes, onResumes knows which fragment is the active one.  ```setRequestedOrientation``` gets run and the value is changed from 0 to 1. But that has no affect on the on screen orientation

Comment: How did you solved it? I've the same problem